# How to get data from JSON decoded array?

Tags: php, json

I have used json decode function in php and decoded my data.

```
$str_json_array_decoded = json_decode($msg, true);
print_r($str_json_array_decoded);
```

The data after decode is like this

```
Array ( [FormatId] => TagValues [ApiVersion] => 1 [CollectionId] => 0 [TagData] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Time] => 2019-09-25T16:53:04.913+05:00 [Values] => Array ( [M1_Current_A] => 9.1834094859527E-41 [M1_Current_B] => 0 [M1_Current_C] => 0 [M1_Current_N] => 0 [M1_Current_Avg] => 0 [M1_Voltage_A_B] => 410 [M1_Voltage_B_C] => 415.95120239258 [M1_Voltage_C_A] => 413.74435424805 [M1_Voltage_L_L_Avg] => 412.47543334961 [M1_Voltage_A_N] => 237.6951751709 [M1_Voltage_B_N] => 238.61717224121 [M1_Voltage_C_N] => 239.98849487305 [M1_Voltage_L_N_Avg] => 238.99998474121 [M1_Active_Power_A] => 2.571382682036E-41 [M1_Active_Power_B] => 0 [M1_Active_Power_C] => 0 [M1_Active_Power_Total] => 0 [M1_Frequency] => 50.499996185303 [M1_Wapda_KWH] => 28.375 ) ) ) ) Array ( [FormatId] => TagValues [ApiVersion] => 1 [CollectionId] => 1 [TagData] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Time] => 2019-09-25T16:53:05.013+05:00 [Values] => Array ( [M2_Current_A] => 3.2031247615814 [M2_Current_B] => 3.0869035720825 [M2_Current_C] => 3.3190958499908 [M2_Current_N] => 0.88120329380035 [M2_Current_Avg] => 3.1875 [M2_Voltage_A_B] => 411.83999633789 [M2_Voltage_B_C] => 415.75802612305 [M2_Voltage_C_A] => 413.35525512695 [M2_Voltage_L_L_Avg] => 412.42272949219 [M2_Voltage_A_N] => 237.58934020996 [M2_Voltage_B_N] => 238.55459594727 [M2_Voltage_C_N] => 239.78469848633 [M2_Voltage_L_N_Avg] => 238.99998474121 [M2_Active_Power_A] => 0.68328124284744 [M2_Active_Power_B] => 0.66681015491486 [M2_Active_Power_C] => 0.74112546443939 [M2_Active_Power_Total] => 2.0859861373901 [M2_PF] => 0.92845875024796 [M2_Frequency] => 50.499996185303 [M2_Wapda_KWH] => 920 ) ) ) ) Array ( [FormatId] => TagValues [ApiVersion] => 1 [CollectionId] => 2 [TagData] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Time] => 2019-09-25T16:53:05.413+05:00 [Values] => Array ( [M3_Current_A] => 9.1834094859527E-41 [M3_Current_B] => 2.34375 [M3_Current_C] => 2.2494165897369 [M3_Current_N] => 6.3986090478E-41 [M3_Current_Avg] => 1.53125 [M3_Voltage_A_B] => 410 [M3_Voltage_B_C] => 415.80212402344 [M3_Voltage_C_A] => 411.28396606445 [M3_Voltage_L_L_Avg] => 413.97732543945 [M3_Voltage_A_N] => 237.51055908203 [M3_Voltage_B_N] => 238.23742675781 [M3_Voltage_C_N] => 239.80584716797 [M3_Voltage_L_N_Avg] => 238.99998474121 [M3_Active_Power_A] => 5.1427653640721E-41 [M3_Active_Power_B] => 0.515625 [M3_Active_Power_C] => 0.49006795883179 [M3_Active_Power_Total] => 1.0143409967422 [M3_PF] => 0.91912376880646 [M3_Frequency] => 50.499996185303 [M3_Wapda_KWH] => 1568 ) ) ) ) Array ( [FormatId] => TagValues [ApiVersion] => 1 [CollectionId] => 3 [TagData] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Time] => 2019-09-25T16:53:06.513+05:00 [Values] => Array ( [M4_Current_A] => 3.8749997615814 [M4_Current_B] => 4.0868253707886 [M4_Current_C] => 7.6376371383667 [M4_Current_N] => 4.473376750946 [M4_Current_Avg] => 5.1875 [M4_Voltage_A_B] => 411.2799987793 [M4_Voltage_B_C] => 415.88528442383 [M4_Voltage_C_A] => 411.39370727539 [M4_Voltage_L_L_Avg] => 413.82992553711 [M4_Voltage_A_N] => 237.5181427002 [M4_Voltage_B_N] => 238.19093322754 [M4_Voltage_C_N] => 239.96385192871 [M4_Voltage_L_N_Avg] => 238.99998474121 [M4_Active_Power_A] => -0.86984372138977 [M4_Active_Power_B] => -0.92594647407532 [M4_Active_Power_C] => -1.6923447847366 [M4_Active_Power_Total] => 3.4974818229675 [M4_PF] => 0.9344254732132 [M4_Frequency] => 50.499996185303 [M4_Wapda_KWH] => 4576 ) ) ) ) Array ( [FormatId] => TagValues [ApiVersion] => 1 [CollectionId] => 4 [TagData] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Time] => 2019-09-25T16:53:06.513+05:00 [Values] => Array ( [M5_Current_A] => 15.562499046326 [M5_Current_B] => 7.8933954238892 [M5_Current_C] => 9.3186721801758 [M5_Current_N] => 7.3327360153198 [M5_Current_Avg] => 10.875 [M5_Voltage_A_B] => 410.07998657227 [M5_Voltage_B_C] => 415.4436340332 [M5_Voltage_C_A] => 411.33181762695 [M5_Voltage_L_L_Avg] => 413.9072265625 [M5_Voltage_A_N] => 237.44709777832 [M5_Voltage_B_N] => 238.17098999023 [M5_Voltage_C_N] => 239.78253173828 [M5_Voltage_L_N_Avg] => 238.99998474121 [M5_Active_Power_A] => -3.3556249141693 [M5_Active_Power_B] => -1.6462224721909 [M5_Active_Power_C] => -1.977999329567 [M5_Active_Power_Total] => 6.9782309532166 [M5_PF] => 0.87971574068069 [M5_Frequency] => 50.499996185303 [M5_Wapda_KWH] => 6592 ) ) ) ) Array ( [FormatId] => TagValues [ApiVersion] => 1 [CollectionId] => 5 [TagData] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Time] => 2019-09-25T16:53:05.313+05:00 [Values] => Array ( [M6_Current_A] => 9.1834094859527E-41 [M6_Current_B] => 0 [M6_Current_C] => 0 [M6_Current_N] => 0 [M6_Current_Avg] => 0 [M6_Voltage_A_B] => 410 [M6_Voltage_B_C] => 415.97528076172 [M6_Voltage_C_A] => 411.68307495117 [M6_Voltage_L_L_Avg] => 413.95782470703 [M6_Voltage_A_N] => 237.60270690918 [M6_Voltage_B_N] => 239.25326538086 [M6_Voltage_C_N] => 239.03291320801 [M6_Voltage_L_N_Avg] => 238.99998474121 [M6_Active_Power_A] => 2.2041023545365E-41 [M6_Active_Power_B] => 0 [M6_Active_Power_C] => 0 [M6_Active_Power_Total] => 0 [M6_Frequency] => 50.499996185303 [M6_Wapda_KWH] => 0 ) ) ) )
```

Now i want to get the value of `M1_Current_A` in this array. For that i am using:

```
foreach ($str_json_array_decoded  as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["M1_Current_A"];
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'M1_Current_A' in C:\xampp\htdocs\srtdash-master\srtdash\db.php on line 28

Kindly help me out for getting the data in a right away.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because `M1_Current_A ` is not in the top level array. It's multiple levels deeper.

Comment: what have you tried to debug your issue? Have you tried different 'paths' to get to the value you want?

Comment: @Dirk kindly help me to out to get to that

Comment: @jibsteroos i am trying to use object to get value but nothing is fruitful. I dont have much understanding to json. You kind help is needed.

Comment: In your case it should work by just using `echo $str_json_array_decoded['TagData'][0]['Values']['M1_Current_A'];`. This is not dynamic at all though. Making it dynamic would depend a lot on the general structure of the json you get. Is it always this format?

Comment: Yes this is always this format. Just values changes against them.

Comment: "I dont have much understanding to json" ...actually, since you've decoded the data into a PHP variable, your understanding of JSON is not relevant to accessing this data - the data has ceased to be JSON at this point. Your understanding of how to access data in a PHP array is relevant though. It seems like you have now enhanced this understanding a little bit thanks to Dirk's help.

Comment: @Dirk can you please help to get M1_Current_A in javascript